# Get information from file and put in list

Tags: regex, vb.net

Right now i'm making a program that allows you to mod a game more easier. In the regular game you have to open up files and navigate through the animations. I wanted to make it easier. I've already made the other parts of the program but go to the last part that I need help with. I want to be able to grab all forms of the first animation name and then the inside animation name, make that go along with it. So I can make an easy to use editor. I know this would most likely involve regex and I am fairly bad at it, I am also still trying to RE-learn VB.net after not toying with the language for ages. If someone could help me out, i'd be very thankful:

The file I am trying to load:

```
animation "idle0"
{
    animation "idle_yoga";
};

animation "idle1"
{
    animation "idle_pants";
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want exacty. idle0->idle_yoga and idle1->idle_pants are not clearly-defined relationships (might be linked otherwise), thus there is no reason to rely on Regex (or similar). If there are more examples, please write them down to transmit the ideas clearer.

Comment: For example: I want to get a list of animations a user can change around. I get the first animation (idle0) and I get what animation it's using. I then get the second animation (idle1) and get it's animation inside. The animations inside the brackets are the programmed animations. The one's outside the brackets are the one the game calls. Strange, I know. But I want to then take all of them and put them in arrays and a list to select from.

Comment: Not necessarily strange, but unclear. I understand that your sample code is the kind of inputs the user is expected to introduce in your program. You want a way to parse them such that the elements inside the brackets are added in some kind of collection named after the string outside the brackets? If this is what you want, you would need to define the conditions further; for example: how many elements are expected to be included inside the brackets? How will they be separated (new lines, all in the same line with semi-colons)? Also what control are you planning to use (a textbox)?

Comment: In most of the brackets, there are two things. `blendInTime 0.01;` and the animation thing I put above. Some of them don't though. I am handling them in a richtextbox right now, it's also a string I set. The file it holds is separated by new lines. And i'm trying to put all the data in a `ListBox`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was doing something else in parallel. There you have your code: deals with the sample inputs as you want and is easily adaptable/extensible (and understandable, I guess). Finally, I decided to store everything in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a sample code performing what you are after:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

Try
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("path to the file")
    Dim line As String
    Dim started As Boolean = False
    Dim inside As Boolean = False
    Dim firstInput As String = ""
    Do
        line = sr.ReadLine()

        If (line IsNot Nothing) Then
            If (line.ToLower().Contains("animation")) Then

                If (started AndAlso inside) Then
                    'Animation
                    Dim curItem As String = line.ToLower().Split(New String() {"animation"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Trim()

                    If (curItem.Substring(curItem.Length - 1, 1) = ";") Then curItem = curItem.Substring(0, curItem.Length - 1)
                    curItem = curItem.Replace("""", "")

                    dict.Add(firstInput, curItem)

                    started = False
                    inside = False
                ElseIf (Not inside) Then
                    'Group name
                    Dim curItem As String = line.ToLower().Split(New String() {"animation"}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Trim()

                    curItem = curItem.Replace("""", "")
                    firstInput = curItem

                    started = True
                End If
            ElseIf (started AndAlso line.Contains("{")) Then
                inside = True
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until line Is Nothing
    sr.Close()
Catch
End Try
```

This code reads the information from a file as described (the code you posted line by line) and performs the grouping you want. Finally, I chose a `Dictionary` (`ListBox` is perhaps not the best control for that; you might consider to use a `ListView` better) because the whole point is showing you how can this situation be addressed. I guess that what the code does is pretty clear: you will have to extend/adapt it to your actual requirements, although the main structure should be something on these lines anyway.